# Default reviewers in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Our company is using Team Foundation Server 2015. Is it possible to add one or several persons automatically as reviewers to every pull request? As required *default reviewers*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can add default reviewers to pull requests quite easily.

[image]

If you configure your branch policy you can have different reviewers occur for different code paths. If you want to add default reviewers to all pull requests for that code path you can specify "/*" in the path box. They will then be added to every pull request.